# Why does Moshe have to apply lots of prayer רבוי תפלה for the removal of the עָרֹב in Shmos 8 (26) and the locusts in Shmos 10 (18)?

Tags: tefilla, parshanut-torah-comment, va-eira

[Shmos 8 (24, 25, 26)](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.8.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Paroh asks for Moshe to pray; Moshe says he will and then Moshe does pray for the removal of the   עָרֹב . The verb used for prayer here is וְהַעְתַּרְתִּי  - translated into English as “I will plead”; Rashi says that the implication is רבוי תפלה  lots of prayer.

My question is why is such extra pleading necessary here and for the removal of the locusts in [Shmos 10 (18)](https://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?aid=2492615&jewish=Bo-Torah-Reading.htm&p=2) and not for the other plagues?

Comment: Also by צפרדע Moshe says למתי אעתיר לך.

Comment: @Meir Yes - In response to Paroh's request which was urgent; but Moshe himself prayed with the expression ויצעק משה Shmos 8 (8).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Riva on Torah, Shemos 8:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.8.26?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Riva_on_Torah%2C_Exodus.8.26.1&lang2=he):

> ויעתר אל ה'. כאן במכת ערוב ובמכת ארבה נאמ' ויעתר שהוא לשון רבוי תפלה כמו שפרש"י בפרשת תולדות מה שאין כן בשאר המכות כגון מכת ברד וצפרדעים שנא' בברד ויפרש כפיו אל ה' וצפרדעים ויצעק משה והטעם לפי שאמרו רבותינו גמירי מיהב יהיב משקל לא שקיל ומשה היה חפץ שלא ישאר אחד מהם כדי שלא יהנו המצרים לא בעור ולא בבשר. ועל כן הוצרך משה להרבות בתפלה שיטול הקב"ה מה שנתן. וזה שנא' כאן לא נשאר אחד וכן במכת ארבה נאמר לא נשאר ארבה אחד מה שאין כן בשאר מכות. ואין להקשות ממה שאמר פרעה העתירו גם בברד ובצפרדעים כי הוא היה סבור שיצטרך להרבות בתפלה להסיר מכה שכבר התחילה:
>
> ...The reason is because our Sages say that we have a tradition that Hashem gives but He doesn't take back, and Moshe wanted that not even one of them should be left, so the Egyptians wouldn't enjoy the skins or the meat. Therefore Moshe had to do lots of prayer, that Hashem should take back what He gave. This is why it says here "not one was left," and also by the locusts, "not one locust was left," unlike by the other plagues. You can't question this based on Pharaoh's request העתירו by the hail and the frogs, because he thought that a lot of prayer would be needed to get rid of a plague that had already started.

Comment: I was about to post this...

Comment: Super. Who please is the Riva?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok: R' Yehuda ben Eliezer, one of the Baalei Hatosfos.